# feedback on tfsbuild setup for mvc app

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild

I am new to TFSBuild but I have been able to create a build definition for my solution. I have a couple questions that help would be great with.

I have created 3 definitions - I wonder if this is the correct way to this.

1. A definition that fires for every check in, builds the code and runs unit tests only
2. A definition runs every night, builds everything, runs all unit and integration tests
3. A definition that I specifically use for deployments - so I specify the environment via a parameter and it builds the code, runs unit and integration tests and ms deploys it to specified environment, again via parameter

When I branch my code etc, I will have to create 3 definitions for each and this could become unmanageable. Feedback on this please?

Is it true that each definition has its own set of build numbers? Can they be shared?

My application is an MVC4 app with VS2012 IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly TFS Build doesn't have very good support for branches, yes this typically means you duplicate your build definitions for each branch.  There are a few custom  build process template that I've seen in the past which try to get around this, but nothing built in.

You could replace #2 with a windows scheduler task to run #1 with custom parameters, not the nicest solution, but could be extended to queue every build definition at midnight with the integration test flag.

For #3 instead of using a build definition to deploy I use an external tool called TFS Deployer, this allows me to use any build to deploy simply by changing the build quality of the build.  Reducing the number of builds that need to be setup by 1 for each branch.

Each build definition has its own build numbers, there's no built in way to share however I believe this is set by the build definition, so you may be able to hack around it somehow.